# Backup file's database

Tags: sql-server

I use Sql Server 2005.
I wanna write code for restore a backup file, and I need to know what is database's name that backup file belongs to it.
How can I know?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get is restore filelistonly ...

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY From DISK = 'C:\temp\mybackup.bak' with file = 1
```

This returns data and the LogicalName field is the SQL Filename of File 1 in the database before it was backed up